# while(*p++) loop doesn't print the first element of the string

Tags: c, pointers

I have a stored a string in a pointer variable which has memory in heap section. When I print the string character by character the first element is skipped.

Example: if `char *p="hello"` when i print character by character using `while(*p++)` loop `'h'` is skipped and output is `"ello"` please can any one explain it?

```
  #include <stdio.h>
  #include <stdlib.h>
  int main() 
  {
    char *p=(char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*20);
    printf("enter string\n");
    scanf("%s",p);
    while(*p++)// value is assign and address is increased
    {
      printf("%c",*p);//why first character is skipped??
    }
    return 0;
  }
```

Comment: You code makes it tricky to use `free`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `while(*p++)` increments the value as soon as the loop starts. By the time the printf statement is reached, `p` has already been incremented.

```
p = 0
while(p++) {   // p = p + 1
   printf('%d', p);  // p = 1 when this executes
}
```

Comment: @marx B  Thank you but how can i do i am supposed to use while loop and my code should be in two line only ?

Comment: use a `do { ... }  while ()` instead. that'll put your increment at the END of the loop: `do { printf(...) } while(p++);`

Comment: or while(*p) and have the increment in the printf.

Comment: @SeriousBusiness: yeah, that'd work too, but later on someone'll try that and blindly copy the p++ through multiple other statements and wonder why the value's jumping by 5 or 6.

Comment: @MarcB the curse of copy pasta

Answer (score 4):

To see the first letter, change `*p` to `p[-1]`, because `p++` has already incremented `p`, so by the time you first use `*p`, `p` already points to the 2nd letter (with index 1).

There are many other ways to solve it, e.g.

```
for (; *p; ++p) {
  putchar(*p);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`while(*p++)` after this statement `p` is incremented and moved ahead. So at `printf()` `p` already points to 2nd character.

Answer (score 0):

The line `while(*p++)` will check the value of `*p` and then increment `p`, **before** entering the body of the loop.  You can improve the code by using a `for` loop

```
for ( ; *p; p++ )
    printf( "%c", *p );
```

or by incrementing the pointer after using it, in the body of the loop

```
while(*p)
    printf( "%c", *p++ );
```